# で role in 他言無用でお願いします

Tags: syntax, particle-で

で is a hard particle for me because I see a strange use of it that I don't understand.

For example, I bump up in this sentence

> 他言無用{たごんむよう}**で**お願いします

I know that で is used to indicate an action that occurred inside a place (*dance inside the house*), or used to clarify by what means the action has been done (*went by bus*). But this is not one of these usages.

What does で mean here?

Answer (score 5):

> 「​他言無用
>   {たごんむよう}
>   **​で**お願{ねが}いします。」 ("Please keep this a secret.")

The 「で」 here indicates the circumstances/conditions under which one performs an action.

The conditions requested by the speaker here are 「他言無用」 ("mum's the word").

The action is 「お願いします」, which is difficult to translate.  It is like "please act ~~", "please do ~~", "**please handle the matter**", etc.

Comment: it's like "if X than that"? because I know for if we use と